# How can I combine each letter from each console.log output?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

So, I'm having a problem, I've been trying to get a string that returns a link of the current user profile picture but when I do a `console.log()` I get something like this:

**Console Output:**

[image]

Here is my TypeScript with the `console.log` output:

```
userImageURL$: Observable<string>;

constructor(
  private userService: UserService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.userImageURL$ = this.user$.pipe(
    switchMap((user: User) => this.userService.getImageURL(user.uid))
  );

  this.userImageURL$.subscribe((test) => console.log(test));
}
```

The `getImageURL()` from the `UserService` just returns a string with the current profile picture of the current user

How can I combine these letters into one string?

Comment: If using a promise wouldn't hurt your implementation, then you can do
```
this.userService.getImageURL(user.uid).toPromise()
.then(url => {
    this.userUmageURL$ = url;
})
```

Comment: @IkennaAnthonyOkafor do what?

Comment: if 'getImageURL' is synchronous, use 'map' operator instead of 'switchMap'.

Answer (score 0):

Join all of the characters together inside the handler function and then print out the string after waiting for the image to finish.

```
var testString = '';
this.userImageURL$.subscribe((test) => testString = testString + test);

var millisecondsToWait = 500;
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(testString);
}, millisecondsToWait);
```

Comment: Really poor answer and overall bad development practice. 
You're waiting 500ms no matter what ( not even guaranteed that the observable is complete ), while existing ways to solve this issue are provided by rxjs ( complete handler, scan, ...)

Comment: This is suitable for debugging and presumably this is what is being done here.  Learning to use a particular library may detract from the problem.  Feel free to provide details of your recommended solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join all the characters and show them on complete.

```
var testString = '';
this.userImageURL$.subscribe(
   test => testString = testString + test.
   err => console.error(err),
   () => console.log(testString) // complete
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is an issue with `this.userService.getImageURL(user.uid)`. I assume it returns some type of  observable that emits multiple values (the chars of a string).

There two possible ways to solve this:

1) Use `scan` operator of `rxjs`:

```
this.userImageURL$ = this.user$.pipe(
    switchMap((user: User) => this.userService.getImageURL(user.uid)),
    scan((accumulator, char) => {
            accumulator += char;
            return accumulator;
         }, '')
  )
```

2) Check the `this.userService.getImageURL(user.uid)` to ensure it returns the whole string:

```
const url$ = this.userService.getImageURL(user.uid).pipe(
    tap(console.log)
);
url$.subscribe(dataChar => console.log(`The data entry is: ${dataChar}`));
```

If the outputs in both `tap` and `subscribe` are the same, the option #2 is incorrect.